Error Starting Hadoop Services - JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found
Brief Description of the Issue:
When attempting to start the Hadoop services within a Docker container, the Java Home (JAVA_HOME) is not being correctly found, resulting in errors when running the Hadoop startup scripts.
Error Problem:
The following errors are observed when trying to start the Hadoop services:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
Code Snippet:
in: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 && $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
out:
root@78a289fdd88e:/# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 && $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [namenode]
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
Starting secondary namenodes [78a289fdd88e]
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.


My dockerfile:
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    ssh \
    rsync \
    wget \
    vim \
    curl \
    net-tools \
    libzip4 \
    libsnappy1v5 \
    libssl-dev \
    sudo && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz -P /tmp && \
    tar -xzf /tmp/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz -C /usr/local && \
    mv /usr/local/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION $HADOOP_HOME && \
    rm /tmp/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    mkdir -p $HADOOP_HOME/logs

RUN mkdir -p /data/dfs/data /data/dfs/name /data/dfs/namesecondary && \
    $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format

RUN sed -i '1s;^;export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64\n;' $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh && \
    sed -i '1s;^;export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64\n;' $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh

CMD ["bash", "-c", "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64; service ssh start; $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh; $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh; while true; do sleep 1000; done"]


Expected Output:
It is expected that the Hadoop services start correctly after setting the JAVA_HOME. However, the errors persist even after setting the JAVA_HOME.

Are you able to execute $JAVA_HOME/bin/java on your own to verify its correct? It's not recommended to run multiple services in one container. Or SSH. Can you not use existing images for the hdfs services?

Full Dockerfile ? FROM ?
